# Python How to Return value in while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

When put return in while loop the loop will stop How to fix it?

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM5',
    baudrate = 9600,
    timeout=1)
while 1:
    x=str(ser.readline())
    x = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", x)
    x = float(x[0])
    return(x) #loop stopped
    print(x)
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Depends on what you want the loop to do instead. Have you tried [`yield`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/1639625)?

Comment: Perhaps you want a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did not try yield yet but my project need to collecting 24 hours is it possible to collect huge data in yield? and i want to send data in realtime

Comment: How about outputing to a file then?

Comment: Yes i already put data in file but I want to show the output to digital display with QtPy too that why i want to return x to drive LCD Number at Qt

Comment: Why use `return` at all? How about just updating the value in the display whilst you're in the `while` loop?

Comment: Just to clarify; you want to continuously read an input from `ser`, do some operations on it and then return it without breaking the continuous part of it?

Comment: instead return put there function which sends data to LCD

Comment: not exactly sure why return is there at all tbh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply take your

```
x=str(ser.readline())
x = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", x)
x = float(x[0])
return(x) #loop stopped
```

put it into a function like

```
def foo(ser):
    x=str(ser.readline())
    x = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", x)
    x = float(x[0])
    return(x)
```

and change your while loop to simply be

```
while 1:
    print(foo(ser))
```

However @developius had a better solution which would look something like

```
while 1:
    x=str(ser.readline())
    x = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", x)
    x = float(x[0])
    print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for advice Dillanm i will try i am a beginner of coding

Comment: @JuizyJ. we all have to start somewhere! The Python docs are pretty good on their own, I also found [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python) and [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/) to be pretty good when I was learning Python, particularly Codecademy since it's interactive and gives immediate feedback! (and they're both free too!)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the values continuously to a separate piece of code, you can use `yield`.

You can modify your code as followed:

```
def func():
    while 1:
        x=str(ser.readline())
        x = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", x)
        x = float(x[0])
        yield x
```

And then call the function. Note that f will be a generator so you will have to loop over it as below.

```
f = func()
for i in f:
    print(i) # or use i for any purpose
```

Reference: [here](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)

Comment: this worked ...!! i used for cv2.Vid while condition... <3<3

Answer (score -2):

u can try this one

```
while 1:
    x=str(ser.readline())
    x = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", x)
    x = float(x[0])
return x
```